# Getting issued the skilled worker visa of UK by practicing as a physiotherapist in Canada

Tags: united-kingdom, canada

I am a citizen of the South Asian country India and I am trying to get into Canada for practicing there as a physiotherapist. I am consequentially thinking to apply to the Permanent Residence (PR) and citizenship of the country Canada, if I happen to be in full time employment in the country Canada for at least five 5 years.

Will I be able to practice as a physiotherapist in the UK if I have some amount of work experience by practicing as a physiotherapist in Canada?

Will Canadian work experience by practicing as a physiotherapist provide me with required credentials to work in the UK as a physiotherapist?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  Questions about work qualifications aren't really our expertise, you're probably better off consulting professional orgs in the UK.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to become a PR and then a citizen of Canada or of the UK?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP can easily find the answer on [Chartered Society of Physiotherapy](https://www.csp.org.uk/careers-jobs/working-united-kingdom) by doing some brief internet research

Comment: @Traveller lack of research is a reason to downvote, not to close.  If you want to point the asker of the question to a particular resource, you should do that in an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: vikworks: the title of your question asks about getting a visa, while the body asks about professional credentials.  These are distinct matters that should probably be the subject of separate questions.